# A better way to say "at the infringement of which"?

Tags: grammar, idioms, idiomatic-language

> Require users to get a proper permit **at the infringement of which**
>   they will be put into prison.

I am pretty sure it's not grammatical, or is it? Anyway, is there a better way to say this? I can't think of a better way, but there has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United States we would say "Require users to get a proper permit on pain of imprisonment” or “on penalty of imprisonment."

> At the beginning of each trial day, Sergeant-at-Arms Michael Stenger will declare, "Hear ye! Hear ye! Hear ye! All persons are commanded to keep silent, on pain of imprisonment." - From "Do chatty senators really face jail time during impeachment?" on [rollcall.com](https://www.rollcall.com/2020/01/16/do-chatty-senators-really-face-jail-time-during-impeachment/)

Similar usages include "on pain/penalty of dismissal," "on pain/penalty of a fine," "on pain/penalty of deportation," "on pain/penalty of death," etc.

Another option would be "require users to get a proper permit or face the possibility of imprisonment."